# how to create a global client side socket android

Tags: android

this code of mine is giving me a headache ... i've made two activities login and signup. when i try to transfer the socket made in login page to signup page, by extending a class from Application and keeping a global socket there, i get the error illegalmonitorstateexception : object not locked by thread b4 wait... have a look at the code and help me clear the error please :D

part for setting the socket in login activity

ApplicationExtension.setSocket(socket);

and the getting part in signup

socket=ApplicationExtension.userSocket;

my extended class

```
package com.example.secroid;
```

import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Application;

public class ApplicationExtension extends Application {

```
public static Socket userSocket;


public static Socket getSocket()
{
    return userSocket;
}
public static void setSocket(Socket newSocket)
{
    userSocket=newSocket;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you need a socket connection for both activities, its probably best to create a Service and let it own the socket, with both activities binding to the service.

Comment: can u tell me how to do that?